# I want to add 'active' class only for the selected div in React JS

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

let cInActive = 'inactive';
let cActive = 'active';

export default function App() {
  const [addClass, setAddClass] = useState(cInActive);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setAddClass(cActive);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={addClass} onClick={handleClick}>
        click here 1
      </div>
      <br />
      <div className={addClass} onClick={handleClick}>
        click here 2
      </div>
      <br />
      <div className={addClass} onClick={handleClick}>
        click here 3
      </div>
      <br />
      <div className={addClass} onClick={handleClick}>
        click here 4
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Find the stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-deukb1?file=src%2FApp.js

I want to add 'active' class only for the selected div in React JS...

Comment: Is more than one allowed to be selected at once?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your requirements, the best way to accomplish this will be different.

### Only one selected at a time.

To force only one item being selected at a time, the best method is to store an identifier of the selected `div` in state and then determine during the render what class it should get.

In this example I'm making use of a pattern called currying, where you call a function in the render that creates a closure so that the number is correct for each handler.

*Note - I used inline styles instead of a class for simplicity, but the pattern is the same*.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const active = {backgroundColor: 'green'}
const inactive = {}

function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);
  const handleClick = (divNum) => () => {
    setSelected(divNum);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={selected == 1 ? active : inactive} onClick={handleClick(1)}>
        click here 1
      </div>
      <br />
      <div style={selected == 2 ? active : inactive} onClick={handleClick(2)}>
        click here 2
      </div>
      <br />
      <div style={selected == 3 ? active : inactive} onClick={handleClick(3)}>
        click here 3
      </div>
      <br />
      <div style={selected == 4 ? active : inactive} onClick={handleClick(4)}>
        click here 4
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

### Multiple items selected at a time

If you don't need to limit to once selection at a time, the best way to accomplish this changes.

While you could still do it with a single state/component, it would be easier to move the selection logic into a new reusable component as follows:

```js
const { useState } = React;

const active = {backgroundColor: 'green'}
const inactive = {}

function SelectableDiv(props) {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setSelected(!selected);
  };
  return (
    <div style={selected ? active : inactive} onClick={handleClick}>
      click here {props.number}
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <br />
      <SelectableDiv number={1} />
      <br />
      <SelectableDiv number={2} />
      <br />
      <SelectableDiv number={3} />
      <br />
      <SelectableDiv number={4} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```